# how to return the value from one pybot command and then use it other testsuite

Tags: python, jenkins, robotframework

Currently I have two different test suites. 
In first test suite, I am have three verification and i want to return the variable(tag1, tag2 and tag3) from pybot command for the that execution has passed.

In the second test suite, we have mentioned three different tags, tag1, tag2 and tag3 for all the test cases. In the bases of condition Pass in first test suite, I want to run the test cases from test suite 2.

Comment: Use `Set Global Variable`.

Comment: Can you please give the example.

Comment: There are some examples in the [Documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable)